# Редирект на главную относительно текущего модуля?

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет!

Хочу автоматом перекинуть на главную, относительно текущего контекста.

Использую этот код в шапке, на view.

```
$this->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'meta',
    'http-equiv' => 'refresh',
    'content' => "5; $this->context->module->homeUrl",
    ]);
```

Выдает ошибку c этим кодом($this->context->module->homeUrl)

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\ErrorException: Object of class app\...\DefaultController
could not be converted to string in C:\....\error.php:15
Stack trace:
```

Но при вызове этого кода ($this->context->module->homeUrl) через var_dump, выводится строка string(7) /admin/

В чем может быть проблема?
В метатегах выводится не строка, а в других местах норм, как строка.

Comment: `'content' => "5; $this->context->module->homeUrl",` это и есть 15 строка с ошибкой в файле `C:\....\error.php`

Comment: Да, так и есть, но почему её не воспринимает как строку? если это строка) Если вывести этот же код на view ниже, где нибудь, то все нормально. Или закинуть в Html::a(), также будет работать ссылка.

Comment: можно было бы конечно передать через контроллер, но смысл, если я использую эту страницу как отстойник(404), и не использую экшены.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'meta',
    'http-equiv' => 'refresh',
    'content' => "5;{$this->context->module->homeUrl}",
    ]);
```

Добавил {} и решил проблему.